# Does firebase store the push notifications sent by the firebase sdk to mobile applications?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using googleapis for sending push notifications using this api https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send?authuser=0

I want to know whether google store the push notifications sent by this API from my web application to my mobile app.

Asking this question because users data is private and they don't want to store their data on any of the servers even the timings of the API call.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every device could be offline, if you send a message, this message should be stored somewhere and then be delivered to the device after it has connected to the internet

Comment: Hi Ahmad, thanks for the response it helps. But from where a normal google account user can see this sent notifications. Please help

Comment: As far as I know, the message is not visible to the users themselves. The message is delivered to the App, through the **Google Play Service** process.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know whether Google stores the push notifications sent by this API from my web application to my mobile app.

Yes, the Android OS can store the notifications on the mobile device in a section called "Notification History". By default, this section is disabled. So you need to explicitly enable it in order to have the notifications history active, and as far as I know, this section only stores the past 24 hours of notifications.

Comment: Hey Sheraz. Can I help you with other information?